# how to implement a complex query on multiple dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I have a processed some data and partitioned it as
/home/hdfs/A
/home/hdfs/B
/home/hdfs/C
/home/hdfs/D

I am provided with an expression like
("A"OR"B")AND("C"OR"D")
this expression may vary in size and usecase like
("A"AND"B")OR("C"AND"D")

AND --> inner join
OR --> union
the schema is single column
How to apply operator between various dataset after reading them?

Comment: can you provide a test data and the expected output. that will really help in answering better.

Comment: I have some dataset with ids. I want to perform join and union based on what user selects. the dataset is single column with only ids.
On UI it would look like ("A"OR"B")AND("C"OR"D")  --> but in backend I want to perform A.join(B).union(C.join(D)).. the issue here is there is no limit to ABCD dataset.
It can be like ("A"OR"B")AND("C"OR"D") AND("E"OR"F") 
how to implement it in backend.